# Sequlize equivalent One to many RelationShip in MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, orm, phpmyadmin

I have this relationship in Node.js by sequelize. How can I create this relationship in PhpMyAdmin?

```js
CompanyModel.hasMany(ProjectModel, {
    as: 'ProjectsInCompany',
    foreignKey: {
        name: 'companyId',
        allowNull: false
    }
});

ProjectModel.belongsTo(CompanyModel, {
    as: 'Company',
    foreignKey: {
        name: 'companyId',
        allowNull: false
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to use phpMyAdmin to create the database and table definitions? Because phpMyAdmin is not a DBMS, its a tool written in PHP that helps us play with MySQL databases

Comment: @RiggsFolly  Yes,I want to create this relationship by phpMyAdmin , How can i do it ?,Or if i can't do it , How can i create instructions to create one to many relashionship By mysql ?

Comment: You can use migrations. Sequelize will do the job for you

Comment: I think you are looking for MySql ORM for PHP and doctrine is one of the famous one. For mapping & association pls refer https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/association-mapping.html

Comment: @Vipul Patil I use mySql with NodeJs Not with Php , and what you think for this ?

Comment: @HibaMuhannad  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8XjfBKFIPQw

Comment: Do you want to modify an existing table or create a new one? Which part of the sequence are you having trouble with? phpMyAdmin's graphical interface has checkboxes or dropdown menus for each of the attributes you're specifying, so please provide additional information about what part exactly is not working for you. Perhaps a screenshot from in phpMyAdmin would help us, too.